# How to decrypt to get back the original string after encryption?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, encryption, public-key-encryption

I am new to iOS and Swift. I wanted to encrypt a string using the public key. The public key was like this:

```
"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
Some String
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
```

I searched for it and got and implemented the following code:

```
static func encrypt(string: String, publicKey: String?) -> String? {
        guard let publicKey = publicKey else { return nil }

        let keyString = publicKey.replacingOccurrences(of: "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", with: "")
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: keyString) else { return nil }

        var attributes: CFDictionary {
            return [kSecAttrKeyType         : kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
                    kSecAttrKeyClass        : kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
                    kSecAttrKeySizeInBits   : 2048,
                    kSecReturnPersistentRef : kCFBooleanTrue] as CFDictionary
        }

        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>? = nil
        guard let secKey = SecKeyCreateWithData(data as CFData, attributes, &error) else {
            print(error.debugDescription)
            return nil
        }
        return encrypt(string: string, publicKey: secKey)
    }

    static func encrypt(string: String, publicKey: SecKey) -> String? {
        let buffer = [UInt8](string.utf8)

        var keySize   = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKey)
        var keyBuffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: keySize)

        // Encrypto  should less than key length
        guard SecKeyEncrypt(publicKey, SecPadding.PKCS1, buffer, buffer.count, &keyBuffer, &keySize) == errSecSuccess else { return nil }
        return Data(bytes: keyBuffer, count: keySize).base64EncodedString()
    }
```

Thanks to StackOverflow again. Now the problem is i am not able to decrypt the encrypted string that is returned by this function. For encoding i wanted a 2048bit size.
For Android this is how it was done for encryption:

```
public String encryptKey() throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidKeyException, CertificateException {

 

        publicKey = getPublicKey();

 

        Cipher oaepFromAlgo = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING");
        oaepFromAlgo.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey );
        //byte[] ct = oaepFromAlgo.doFinal(secretKey.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] ct = oaepFromAlgo.doFinal(secretKey.getEncoded());
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ct);
        }
        else{
            return android.util.Base64.encodeToString(ct,android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
        }
    }

 

    private PublicKey getPublicKey() throws CertificateException {
        CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)f.generateCertificate(getTrustedCertificatesInputStream());
        return certificate.getPublicKey();
    }
```

It would be really helpful if anyone could guide me in the right path on how to decrypt and if my encryption process is similar to that of android.

Answer (score 0):

A heartfelt thanks to everyone who tried to solve it. I managed to do it on my own. Instead of public key as string, i extracted public key as secKey by converting my crt file to der